# Please merge [tag:extended-desktop] [tag:multiple-desktop]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

Those 2 tags are exact duplicates : [extended-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extended-desktop)[multiple-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-desktop) isn’t it ?

Comment: This is an interesting one.  A lot of people use the terms interchangeably, and neither tag has guidance.  Some people differentiate adding screen real estate vs. managing multi-screen content, but there isn't consistency in which term is used for each.  There are 65 questions between them and only 6 are tagged with both.  But in practice, the two tags are used the same way.  So people have a preference and both terms should be accessible.  Any thoughts on which would be the better primary tag?  There are 25 desktops vs. 40 displays, so quantities would favor display.

Comment: @fixer1234 : I have no ideas.

Comment: I would recommend [tag:extended-desktop] as the primary tag. To me at least it is more immediately apparent as to the point of the question.

Comment: @Burgi : you should write it in an answer. I have really no ideas of what should be the primary tag. I want action to be taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `extend-display` would be the most correct in my opinion, I feel like a lot of people would use `extend-desktop` if they didn't think about it. But the tag usage frequency seems to prove me wrong.

When attempting to adjust the settings to extend your display, Windows does use the words 'Extend these displays`.

From all of my own personal experience, I noticed that almost everyone refers to their display as their desktop. "How do I extend my desktop?", "How do I mirror my desktop?", etc.

I went to the almighty Google to solve this and typed a query `Extend d` and 4 results were:

1. extend definition
2. extend display mac
3. extend display
4. extend display windows 7

So I vote `extend-display`.

Comment: "Display" can refer to either the hardware or the content.  "Desktop" refers to the content, and only sort of implies that you need hardware to accomplish it.  Display is probably the more universal term, and less likely to look like the "wrong" tag.

Comment: @fixer1234 : display doesn’t have to display a windowed system. It can also be a full console.

Comment: @DrZoo : what about [tag:multiple-desktop] ?

Comment: @user2284570 is multiple-desktop the tag that was implemented?

Comment: @DrZoo : no, but it looks like to be a third duplicate I forgot in the original question.

Comment: @user2284570 I got looking into the questions that are tagged multiple-desktop and they are of the same nature as `extended-desktop`, yet differ enough from the tag `multiple-display`. The `multiple-display` tag has more hardware related questions, and `multiple-desktop` is more related to software. I'd say it could be merged with `extended-desktop`